# How to install themes in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, themes, unity-tweak-tool

how can I install other themes in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?
I've tried some methods but none of them  work.

1) first, I  tried to put my new themes in `~/.themes` folder, but that folder doesn't exist...

[image]

2) after that I had tried to install Unity Tweaks Tool, but with this I can add what themes I want from other site, for example http://www.ubuntuthemes.org/  . If I want to download one or more themes from this site I can used it with that program, or I don't know how..

3) and the last solution that I had found,(which didn't work for me) was to put my themes in `/urs/share/theme` and reboot after that. But it still didn't work.

So, does anyone have any idea of how can I solve this problem? How I can add more themes to my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 4):

If the `.themes` directory doesn't exist in your user's `/home` directory, you can just create it, then put any downloaded themes in there.

This alone will not install the theme, that's where the `unity-tweak-tool` comes in. This [guide](http://itsfoss.com/how-to-install-themes-in-ubuntu-13-10/) is nice and clear, they only add the Numix ppa as an example, but the rest of the instructions should be applicable.

Comment: It dont work.. I've fallow all that tutorial and after I used the command `sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme-shine numix-icon-theme-circle`
I've receive a error   **E: Unable to locate package numix-icon-theme-shine**

Comment: And yes, I've created the folder with name .themes

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna install a gtk/unity theme, then put it in `~/.themes`; if you wanna install a icon/cursor theme, put it in `~/.icons`. Then use `unity-tweak-tool` to choose the one you like.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:numix/ppa  
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

You can also change theme using "ubuntu tweek" tool this is better than "unity tweak"

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```